# Threejs: How to add a model to a canvas?

Tags: three.js

I need your help. I'm trying to add my model to a canvas I've added to the html-document. But the following code doesn't work:

```
function main() {
            
    const container = document.querySelector( "#machine-model" );
    let height = container.offsetHeight;                    // Offset height = element + padding + border + scrollbar
    let width = container.offsetWidth;

    const fov = 75;
    const aspect = width / height;
    const near = 0.1;
    const far = 5;
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( fov, aspect, near, far );
    camera.position.x = 8.3;
    camera.position.y = 11.7;
    camera.position.z = -8;
    camera.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ) );

    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xFFFFFF );         // changes background color from black to white

    const ambiLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xFFFFFF, 0.5 );
    scene.add( ambiLight );
    
    const spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xFFFFFF, 0.6 );
    spotLight.position.set( 13.6, 20.1, -13.9 );
    spotLight.castShadow = true;
    scene.add( spotLight );

    const gltfLoader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    gltfLoader.load( "model/M-62300-00-811-0_002.glb", function( gltf ) {

        const model = gltf.scene;
        model.rotateX( -Math.PI/2 );
        console.log( model );
        scene.add( model );
        
    });

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: container, antialias: true, alpha: true } );       // alpha = true -> alpha = 0
    renderer.setSize( width, height );

    function render() {

        renderer.render( scene, camera );

        requestAnimationFrame( render );

    }

    requestAnimationFrame( render );

};

main();
```

Here's a [link to working JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/092vjL4r/6/)

If I add the id of my canvas to the canvas parameter of the renderer, I don't need to do it with appendChild, right?

Comment: Do you get any errors, what is the value of `container` if you `console.log` it?

Comment: @Berthur I do not get any errors. If I log the container after the querySelector i get this: <canvas id="machine-model" data-engine="three.js r143" width="1536" height="722" style="width: 1536px; height: 722px;"></canvas>

Comment: Then based on what observation does it not work? Could you perhaps put your program in a jsfiddle so we can easier try it?

Comment: I only get a white page. The model isn't shown. I can show you my full code but I can't share the glb file.

Comment: No need to share the model. In fact, if you can reproduce this issue with a simple cube, then all the better: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This was my first time working with jsfiddle. Hope this is okay: https://jsfiddle.net/092vjL4r/6/

Comment: There are a few issues with your JSFiddle. You're importing THREE.js at version `0.145` but GLTFLoader at version `0.126`. These need to match. Also, you can't import `.glb` files directly from Github like this due to [Cross-Origin resource sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your fiddle, the canvas seems to be passed successfully. The problem instead seems to be your `far` distance, which you set to *5*, even though you place your camera quite far away from the origin.

Try instead with a larger `far` value, say *1000*.

Comment: I set the three coordinates of the camera to 1000. The page is still white. I've imported the model (not the cube!) in the threejs editor before. The camera parameter of my script worked for this model in the editor.

Comment: @stoex Instead of your glb model, can you load a simple three.js cube? I could do that in your demo, when I set the camera far distance to 1000 (leaving the camera coordinate as it is).

Comment: Ah sorry i didn't get what you meant with far. If I set the far to 1000 everything works fine. Sometimes it's better to think about what I'm doing. Thank you!